# Get 3rd party application window property c#

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface

I'm developing a WPF application.
My app will control most of the 3rd party app UI.

So far so good.
But now I stuck at combo box.

I can get the handle of the 3rd party window.
But next step is I have to control the combo box.

My guess I have to get the handle of the combobox first.
So, how do I get the handle for the combo box on the 3rd party UI ?
Using spy++ I can detect it.
But how to achieved this programmatically ?

I think only after I can get the combo box handle, then I will be able to get info of the combo box from that handle itself. 
Since the combo box will be multiple, I guess I need to find a way to read a window property from it's window handle, which I already have.

Any suggestion ?

Comment: If the 3rd party application is really using WPF, you will be out of luck with control handles (child controls usually don't have a HWND in WPF). Have a look at [UI Automation API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/ui-automation/ui-automation-fundamentals) instead.

Comment: If you mean the dropdown part of the combobox: This one is very hard, because it is no ordinary child window of the third party program's window but belongs to Windows itself. The reason is, that combobox dropdowns might stick out of the top level window the combobox belongs to.
So if your code relies on the fact that the combobox dropdown is a child window of the third party program's window, then you will have to change your code.

Comment: See following posting : https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/cc61ed2d-2370-40f8-92a9-032432ae10e4/emergency-how-to-get-a-handle-of-a-window-and-usercontrol?forum=wpf

Comment: @HeinzKessler change which code ? I can't change the 3rd party app code since it is not mine. But if you are talking about my WPF code, then which part I have to change ?

Comment: @KlausGütter I don't even know if the 3rd party app is a WPF app or not. So, I'm not sure if the UI automation will be able to be used.

Comment: @Lyn: I mean your code. With the handle to the 3rd Party item, use the Windows API function `GetDlgItem` using the controls ID. You find the control ID in Spy++'s property inspector. In order to use `GetDlgItem` you will need some P/Invoke magic. If you are not familiar with P/Invoke, go to http://www.pinvoke.net/ and use their VS extension, which is much better than using their web page directly.

Comment: @Lyn: Above I mean "3rd party window", not "3rd party item". And all I wrote assuning that the 3rd party window is a regular Windows dialog, which seems to be the case as you can identify the combo box using Spy++

Comment: Thank you very much @HeinzKessler I think pinvoke,net is the key. From there I can call the API to get various info which hopefully existed. And yes it is can be inspected using Spy++ though I dont know if that's means it is a regular Windows dialog or not.

Although, for the pinvoke.net itself it is quite confusing for a first timer like me. But there is first for everything.

Comment: @Lyn: You're welcome. If Spy++ is able to identify the controls, and if Spy++ shows a control ID for them, it will be a normal Windows dialog. Good luck with P/Invoke. You will have to gain a minimum amount of knowledge about how the Windows API works. Well, it's based on technologies from the Eigthies...
If you need more assistance, feel free to contact me via mail, mail address in my profile.